# Error from YearList plugin: Non-static method Yearlist::usage() should not be called statically

Tags: plugin

I recently noticed that I was getting an error message from one of my plugins [YearList](https://github.com/ryanirelan/ri.yearlist.ee_addon.2.0). The page the error occurs on seems to function as expected despite the error, but I would like to resolve the error or at the very least hide it from view.

The error being displayed is:

```
Message: Non-static method Yearlist::usage() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

And the error says it is occuring on this line of `pi.yearlist.php`

```
$plugin_info = array(
                 'pi_usage'         => Yearlist::usage()
               );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed it by changing this line:

```
function usage()
```

To this:

```
public static function usage()
```

Source: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20352/plugins-through-php-warning-with-strict-errors-on